# Attempted delete (or overwrite) of read-only file fails to redirect "STDERR"

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, command-prompt

I have a batch file that at some point may have to delete a file (or overwrite an existing file). I do this in in a standard way like this:

```
c:\>del somefile
```

This (in cases where the file is "read only") of course results in the error message:

```
Access is denied.
```

In the case that the delete command fails, I want to test if the delete was successful by checking if the file exists after the delete. So, I want to redirect the output (`STDOUT`) and error output (`STDERR`) to "nul" and then use "`if file exists ...`" after the delete command to see if further action is required:

```
del somefile 2>&1 >nul
if exists somefile goto :someplace
```

The problem is, it appears that the redirection of `STDERR` fails because I still get the error message:

```
c:\>del somefile 2>&1 >nul
Access is denied.

c:\>
```

This happens whether I am executing this from a batch file or from the command prompt.

I understand I can use the `/F` (Force) switch for `del` to force the deletion (and avoid the error message) like this:

```
c:\>del /F somefile 2>&1 >nul

c:\>
```

But, I lose the ability to know about situation and take other action if necessary (like prompting the user ...). Also, there is the (rare) possibility that the delete command fails for other reason (like the file is in use), in which case I will probably still see the redirection of `STDERR` fail.

A workaround is to use the `attrib` command (before the `delete` command) to examine the "read only" status of the file, but this is a bit involved, and is probably best done using "`REGEX`" with an external command like "`grep`" or "`sed`" (still very doable).

Is this behavior of "`cmd.exe`" known and is there some reason it's not considered a "bug"?

Is there some way to force "`cmd.exe`" to redirect this `Access is denied.` message?

Comment: Do not use the title to say "resolved"; instead, accept an answer (you already did).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `2>&1 >nul`, you should use `>nul 2>&1`. when saying `2>&1`, you don't make it output to the default output, you make the error output redirect to a copy of the default output. However, because this gets interpreted from left to right, you first redirect error output to a copy of the default output, so to the screen, and then you redirect *only* the default output to nul.

Comment: Yes!! Of course, I knew that and I don't know how I got those backward and missed it when troubleshooting... Nevermind =)